# How to call COM Interop DLL from Native C (win32)

Tags: c, native, com-interop

I have a C Program (WIN32) and I have to call a 3th party "COM Interop" DLL in my program. 
I could not find any helpfull result in google. (Returns generaly "calling COM DLL from Managed Code")
What are the directives?

Is there any example or tutorial for this?

Thanks.

Murat.

Comment: So, we cannot use COM Interop DLL in C Code?

Answer (score 0):

These two might help you:

[How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)

[Call Managed DLL written in C# from Unmanged Code VC++](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/234693/Call-Managed-DLL-written-in-Csharp-from-Unmanged-C)